# Someone downloaded my game but it failed on Game Start due to code that doesnt exist

Tags: game-maker

As stated in the title, they get the following error:

```
 ############################################################################################
 FATAL ERROR in
 action number 1
 of Other Event: Game Start
 for object obj_music_controller:

 ds_map_find_value argument 1 incorrect type (undefined) expecting a Number (YYGI32)
 at gml_Script_scr_checkLastLoggedInJson
 ############################################################################################
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 stack frame is
 gml_Script_scr_checkLastLoggedInJson (line -1)
 gml_Object_obj_music_controller_Other_2
```

The function ds_map_find_value() is not being called in the script scr_checkLastLoggedInJson(). (Even if it was, how could it be happening at line -1?)

Nor is it called in the Game Start event of the obj_music_controller object.
I also checked every use of ds_map_find_value() in the entire game and they are all fine.

Furthermore, this is only happening with 1 person. And they have tried uninstalling it and re-downloading. Even after i uploaded a new version of the game, this still happened to them and only them.

EDIT: scr_checkLastLoggedInJson()

---

```
var result = false;


if (file_exists("saveJson.json"))
{
    var saveJson = scr_loadJSONFromFile("saveJson.json");//ds_map
    var saveJsonNames = saveJson[? "Names"]; //ds_list
    var userSaveData = noone;
    var saveJsonSaves = noone;

    if (ds_list_size(saveJsonNames) == 1) //If there is only 1 user, that is the one to load.
    {
        result = true;
        var username = saveJsonNames[| 0];
        global.username = username;
    }
    else
    {
        //Find the user who was last logged in and assign them to global.username.
        for (var i = 0; i < ds_list_size(saveJsonNames); i++)
        {
            var username = saveJsonNames[| i];
            saveJsonSaves = saveJson[? "Saves"];//ds_map


            if (!is_undefined(username))
            {
                userSaveData = saveJsonSaves[? username]; //ds_map

                if (userSaveData[? "Last Logged In"])
                {
                    result = true;
                    global.username = username;
                    ds_map_destroy(userSaveData);
                    ds_map_destroy(saveJsonSaves);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if  (ds_exists(userSaveData, ds_type_map))
    {
        ds_map_destroy(userSaveData);
    }

    if  (ds_exists(saveJsonSaves, ds_type_map))
    {
        ds_map_destroy(saveJsonSaves);
    }

    ds_list_destroy(saveJsonNames);
    ds_map_destroy(saveJson);
}

return result;
```

---

Comment: Can you show us the code for gml_Script_scr_checkLastLoggedInJson ? Even though you don't call this method directly, it might get called as a consequence of something else you're doing.

Comment: `ds_map_find_value` is called anytime you reference `saveJason[? "Some string here"]`, because you're finding the value associated with that input string. In some case it's undefined. It might be where you find a username, then look up a save with that name?

Comment: Hmmm, ok I will add code to look out for this and see what happens.

Comment: I did a game-wide search for ```[? ``` and identified all places where I used this accessor with a variable (like ```[? username]``` in the example above). I then enclosed it and all code related to it in an ```if``` with a condition like ```!is_undefined(username)```. But this didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Actually, maybe ```ds_map_find_value argument 1 incorrect type (undefined) expecting a Number (YYGI32)``` is referring to the ds_map argument of ds_map_find_value(ds_map, value). Because i know GMS starts indexing at 1 instead of 0 for some things and maybe this is one of those things. Furthermore, the ds_map argument would have to always be a number because it is the ID of a ds_map, whereas the second argument can be a string so I will look for places in the code where the map being searched doesnt actually exist.

Comment: Any idea what it means by ```(line -1)``` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it. Idk what caused this, but here we go. My save file is structured like this: `{"Names":[], "Saves":{}}`. Somehow the "Saves" key wasnt created (only in the case of this specific person) so at some point in the code it does `saveJsonSaves = saveJson[? "Saves"]` and then saveJsonSaves is undefined. So i added code to catch this scenario and reconstruct the missing "Saves" key.